# J2ME Manager.CreatePlayer() freeze application for a split second when using the first time

Tags: java-me

When I call for the first time to Manager.CreatePlayer() its freezes my application for a split second and it's a problem for me because I'm writing a game and it's noticeable, what can I do to fix it ?

Comment: It probably happens because the file is loading. In that case, the fix is easy: Just handle the player routines in its own thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the common logics for game are :

**Display loading screen**

Here's all heavy operations are prepared/preloaded and cached, so the game can run smoothly later.
Methods that usually called here are `Manager.createPlayer` and `Player.prefetch()`.
All the image & sound is prepared first, and can be used quickly when game started.

**Start the game (loop)**

As the resource have been prepared/preloaded, now you can use (draw/play) them here.
Use the `Player` instances that has been created & prefetched (from loading screen).
You can call `Player.start()` method here to play the sound.

---

You can read about the Player state (especially about prefetch) [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/mm/jsr135/javax/microedition/media/Player.html).

Notice that you can reuse the `Player` instance and call `start()` method multiple times for playing the same sound. No need to call `createPlayer` again.

Comment: but what if i have couple of different sounds that should be played when different actions occours so how could I prefetch the player with all of them, should I use multiple players ? or should I create each player with each music file prefetch and then when the action occours recreate this player with the correct music file and play it will it work ?

Comment: It is bad idea to recreate the player when game has been started (createPlayer is heavy process). The better approach is creating multiple Players in loading-screen phase, one Player instance for one kind of sound (and don't forget to prefetch them too)

Comment: Except not all devices supports creating multiple Player objects. I've done extensive tests with the Player object, and the only method that ran on all my test devices, was to completely stop, deallocate and null the Player, and then create a new one with the new sound. Trying to re-use an existing Player object crashed certain devices. My advice: Create a class that handles audio. Have the stop() method of that class completely kill the Player, and the start("filename") method of that class create everything all over.